# BtsTask to import policy

Tags: biztalk, policy, biztalk-rule-engine

I am looking for a way to import BRE generated policy with its vocabularies into BizTalk application from a command line (in order to script it) leveraging BtsTask command line tool.

I've searched around, and couldn't find a firm answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell provider for BizTalk.
This allows you to script, amont other things, policy and vocabulary deployment.

This can provide an alternative to MSBuild which is more geared, in my opinion, to the development than to be used to support operations management.

The provider is available on CodePlex:
http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

If the msi for your application includes the BRE rules for that app, then the ImportApp command of BTSTask will publish them to the BRE for that environment.  There isn't a separate BTSTask command for importing policies by themselves.  If for some reason you want to import just the policy with no other artifacts, you can do so by exporting just the rules into an msi by themselves, then use BTSTask ImportApp to import the msi.

Check out this link for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577374.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I tend to disagree. I have downloaded ESB Tookit and it actually leverages BTSTask to import policies from XML. Logically it makes sense to use XML and not MSI. You policy/bindings/VS.NET artifacts should be assembled automatically on build server, not extracted from BizTalk instance into an executable MSI. In any way, I am not entirely sure that the way ESB team did it is the right way, but like that.

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to answer your question literally.  You asked for a way to use BTSTask from the command line (which I did provide), and I didn't want to preach about whether this was the best approach.

I'm currently using MSBuild for deploying our BTS apps, which has a built-in library of BizTalk-related tasks (i.e. BizTalk.BuildGenerator.Tasks.BRE.ImportPolicy for importing BRE policy).  Not sure if you were thinking of heading in the MSBuild direction or not, but I can give you some more detail if you'd like.  If not, good luck, hopefully someone else will have some insight :)